# Looping through Constructor Function in JS is not working

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

I am trying to loop through an array and use that arrays as names for the constructor function. But it says that my constructor function is not defined. Below is the image of my code and its output on the console

*Here is the image of my code and the error message*:

[image: Here is the image of my code and the error message]

```js
function AnimalMaker(name) {
  return {
    speak: function() {
      console.log("my name is", name);
    }
  };
};

var animalNames = ['Sheep', 'Liger', 'Big Bird'];

var farm = [];

for(var i = 0; i < animalNames.length; i++) {
  farm.push(AnimalMaker(animalNames[i]));
}

console.log(farm);
```

Comment: Can you please add your code as text (see this for more details as to why it's a good idea to include your actual code: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551))

Comment: There is something else in the equation as this code alone works as expected. How is it being executed? Error message mentions `eval`

Comment: Yep, there is a problem in you environment. Works well on node and the console.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be making few assumptions here. It looks like your code is being evaluated by some library (the eval call mentioned in the error message). It may happen that it evals the code block by block separately and effectively creating multiple contexts. Now the `AnimalMaker` function is in one, and the call is in another. This way indeed, in the context of the call, the function is not defined.

To cope with that I would define the function in a well known, common context. Eg. if you're executing your code in a browser then you could define your function like this:

```
window.AnimalMaker = function(name) { ... }
```

The call stays the same, has `window` in context and should have no problem calling the function.

(if that doesn't work you probably need to give some more information about how you execute the code)